# Reactjs Material UI state is undefined on event

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a simple app using react and material ui

Main component

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ProjectList from './projectlist';

export default class Application extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    changeProject() {
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="row">
                <div className="col s3">
                    <ProjectList
                        onProjectChangeEvent={this.changeProject}/>
                </div>
            </div>;
    }
}
```

ProjectList component

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import Card from 'material-ui/lib/card/card';
import CardHeader from 'material-ui/lib/card/card-header';
import CardText from 'material-ui/lib/card/card-text';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/lib/flat-button';
import CardActions from 'material-ui/lib/card/card-actions';

// FIXME: Remove when react1.0 is launched
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

export default class ProjectList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: props.data || [],
            changeEvent: props.onProjectChangeEvent
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    openEdit = () => {
        console.debug(this.state);   
    }

    render() {
        return <Card>
                    <CardHeader
                        title="Super Project Title"
                        subtitle="Super Project Subtitle"/>
                    <CardText>
                        Something important
                    </CardText>
                    <CardActions>
                        <FlatButton
                            label="Edit"
                            onTouchTap={this.openEdit}/>
                    </CardActions>
                </Card>;
    }
}
```

when I click the FlatButton, the console.debug(this.state) == undefined? How can I communicate with the Application component from the ProjectList component? I want to send the project object back to the Application. Inside the constructor the props exist, same goes for componentDidMount. But in the event it's undefined. How come?

**Update**
Adding the change suggested by @taylorc93 gives me this error in the console

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: http://localhost:3000/app/components/projectlist.js: Unexpected token (31:13)
  29 |     }
  30 | 
> 31 |     openEdit = () => {
     |              ^
  32 |         console.debug(this.state);   
  33 |     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function as

```
openEdit() {
  console.debug(this.state);   
}
```

Then you can either bind it in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.openEdit = this.openEdit.bind(this);
}
```

and reference it normally:

```
<FlatButton label="Edit" onTouchTap={this.openEdit} />
```

Or just bind it when you reference it (no changes to the constructor necessary):

```
<FlatButton label="Edit" onTouchTap={this.openEdit.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

With the ES6 class changes, React no longer automatically binds `this` to all of your component's methods, just `render`, the constructor, and the lifecycle methods.  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding

Thus, when `openEdit` is fired, `this` is not set to your react component.  The easiest way to fix this is by using a neat trick with ES6 arrow functions like this:

```
openEdit = () => {
  console.debug(this.state);   
}
```

This takes advantage of the lexical `this` binding that arrow functions offer and will correctly bind `this` to your react component.  This might be interesting to you for further reading: http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus/

Hope all of this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but now I get a error in the console, I have updated the post

Comment: Sorry, forgot that property initializers on classes is an ES7 feature.  If you still want to use this (I find it much cleaner), you can enable this in your transpiler.  If you're using babel, this would mean enabling stage 0 proposals

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
openEdit () {
     console.debug(this.state);   
   }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This was my first ans. Next time onward I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!